# Google Search Console reporting 404 errors on /page/x pages which is not a 404

Tags: seo, google-search-console, redirects, 404

hopefully someone here can shed a light on this. Search console on one of my site is reporting a 404 to a bunch of pages on my site but they are not actually 404s.

Here's an example:

examplesite.com/new-blog-post/page/1 <-- This is being tagged as 404 when this page is redirecting to: examplesite.com/new-blog-post

which I assume is normal for a wordpress site to redirect to the main post when adding the pagination link to the url.

Any comments regarding this would be appreciated as I have no clue now as to why this is happening. Thank you

Comment: Did you implement the redirects after Google has crawled your pages? Might need to request a recrawl in Search Console. Also check where Google might be finding those links to the /page/1 pages. Maybe rogue links on pages or your sitemap?